# How to set state and props on a single click event in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following react component which will be used to toggle a menu:

```
var MenuToggle = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <a id="menu-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">
                <i id="closed" className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <i id="open" className="fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        )
    }
});
```

When this component is clicked, I need to toggle it's state so the 'hamburger' icon becomes an 'x' icon. I also need to add a prop to the component so that the parent menu's state can be updated by listening for 'MenuToggle' component to receive the prop. Since I need to do both based on the same click event, I have tried:

```
var MenuToggle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {open: false}
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        var that = this;
        function setTheState() {
            that.setState({open: !that.state.open})
        }
        function setTheProps() {
            that.props.whenClicked
        }
        setTheState()
        setTheProps()
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <a id="menu-toggle" href="javascript:void(0);" onClick={this.handleClick} className={(this.state.open ? 'open' : '')}>
                <i id="closed" className="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <i id="open" className="fa fa-times"></i>
            </a>
        )
    }
});
```

Basically, I am calling the single function 'handleClick' which should set / toggle the state of 'MenuToggle', and add the 'whenClicked' prop.

The result is that the state is toggled but 'whenClicked' is not set. whenClicked needs to be set because the parent component, 'Menu' listens for 'whenClicked' in 'menuToggle'. When 'Menu' hears 'whenClicked', it fires 'handleClick' which toggles it's own state:

```
var Menu = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {open: false, mobi: false}
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
    },
    closeOnMobiScroll: function() {
        /*
        if(this.state.mobi === false) {
            this.setState({open: false})
        }
        */
    },
    updateDimensions: function() {
        $(window).width() >= 767 ? this.setState({mobi: true}) : this.setState({mobi: false});
    },
    componentWillMount: function() {
        this.updateDimensions();
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        $(window).on("resize", this.updateDimensions);
    },
    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        $(window).on("resize", this.updateDimensions);
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div id="menu-wrap">
                <MenuToggle whenClicked={this.handleClick} />
                <div id="menu" className={(this.state.open ? 'open' : '')} >
                    <MenuTitle />
                    <MenuList whenClicked={this.handleClick}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

Is there a way to toggle the state and set the 'whenClicked' prop with one click event?

Comment: It's unclear to me what `this.props.whenClicked` is supposed to be, since you are not doing anything with it. In general: The owner has to pass a callback to the the component and your component has to call it. E.g. the owner does `<MenuToggle onClick={this.updateSomething} />` and your component will do `this.props.onClick()`. It's the owners responsibility to update its state and rerender and update props accordingly.

Comment: OK, I tried to clarify and posted the owner's code too.

Comment: Then all you have to do is actually **call** the function: `that.props.whenClicked()`.

Comment: *facepalm I knew it was some detail I was missing... I copied it out of the inline event originally and didn't think of the changed scope. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

let me see if I can understand this, when clicked:

1. toggle component's state
2. pass the trigger to parent through props

if the above assumption is true, then here's what I am suggesting:

1. as for convention, use "on" and "handle" as prefix
2. [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) could be a good tool to learn since fb is also using it
3. since set state is async, you can use its call back function to trigger things when the state is set.
4. pass the new state to its parent is a good practice to let the parent know the child's state

here's the modified version:

```js
var MenuToggle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isOpen: false
        };
    },
    _handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen}, function() {
            this.props.onClick(this.state.isOpen);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var iconClass = classNames('fa', this.state.isOpen ? 'fa-times' : 'fa-bars');
        return(
            <a id="menu-toggle" onClick={this._handleClick}>
                <i className={iconClass}></i>
            </a>
        )
    }
});
```

hope this helps =)

Comment: Your way if setting state in _handleClick() and passing props to parent, is actually good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
var MenuToggle = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            isOpen: false
        };
    },
    _handleClick: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({isOpen: !this.state.isOpen}, function() {
            this.props.onClick(this.state.isOpen);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var iconClass = classNames('fa', this.state.isOpen ? 'fa-times' : 'fa-bars');
        return(
            <a id="menu-toggle" onClick={this._handleClick}>
                <i className={iconClass}></i>
            </a>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain your question. so it will help to future visitors.